# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't boot and I can't load HD

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I've been the happy user of Ubuntu 14.04 for the past year. However, a few days ago my laptop stopped booting, when I turned it on. I can hear the hard drive working but the screen remains pitch black - nothing comes on - not even the boot menu.

It's a pretty old laptop, and I was going to change it anyway, but I have a few things I'd like to get out of the hard drive (same old situation, huh?). So I thought I'd just remove the hard drive from the computer, throw it in a hard disk box, connect it to my new computer (Win 10 installation) and copy-paste the things. Simple!

The thing is that my new computer can't find the hard drive from the old one. I've also tried on my work computer (Win 7 installation) with the same result. Is there any way I can get either my new computer or my work computer to load the hard drive without having to format it?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Windows cannot read ext4 formatted data without installing extra software and jumping through some hoops.

**Option one:**

You will need to boot from a live session of Ubuntu or any other linux distro from a USB or a burned disk.

Once you are booted up with a linux distro, you should be able to transfer and/or copy the data from the old hard drive.

**Option two:**

You should be able to replace the existing hard drive on windows 7 computer with the old hard drive that has Ubuntu on it.

Just replace the hard drive and boot up Ubuntu and it should boot up with little to no issues as Ubuntu doesn't need to download any drivers because the drivers are built into the kernel.

Once booted up, you can transfer or copy the data.

When you are done, just swap the windows 7 hard drive back into the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting from a live CD? If it doesn't work, either your live CD is wrong, or you have a serious hardware problem.

And about the windows computer not being able to mount the HD from the linux one... Are you sure it can mount partitions formatted as ext3/ext4?  Maybe you could try to mount it from a VM running Ubuntu, or from a live CD...